# how to compute unbiased estimator

Tags: statistics

Suppose $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ is a random sample of size n drawn from a Poisson pdf where $\lambda$ is an unknown parameter. Show that $\hat \lambda = \bar X$ is unbiased for $\lambda$. For what type of parameter, in general, will the sample mean necessarily be an unbiased estimator? (Hint: The answer is implicit in the derivation showing that $\bar X$ is unbiased for the Poisson $\lambda$)

---

$$E(\bar X) = E(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i)= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^nE(X_i)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda =\lambda$$

---

im totally confused by this idea of unbiasedness? what is it? and how do you compute it in the general sense, whats the first step, second step ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose we have a collection of samples $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ that have been drawn from some fixed probability distribution (Poisson, exponential, normal, etc.) that depends on some unknown parameter $\mu$.

We often want to use the samples to estimate the value of $\mu$. To this end we come up with functions that take in $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ and return an estimate of $\mu$. Any such function is called an *estimator*.

Now, some estimators are better or worse than others. For example,

$$f(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n) = 0$$

is clearly a terrible estimator (unless it so happens that $\mu=0$), given that it doesn't use any information provided by the samples.

A basic criteria for an estimator to be any good is that it is *unbiased*, that is, that *on average* it gets the value of $\mu$ correct. Formally, an estimator $f$ is unbiased iff

$$E[f(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)] =\mu.$$

In your case, the estimator is the sample average, that is,

$$f(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i,$$

and it is unbiased since on average it guesses the unknown parameter, $\lambda$, correctly. An example of a biased estimator would be

$$f(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)=1+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i,$$

since $E[f(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)] = 1+\lambda$. On average it gets the value of $\lambda$ wrong by $1$; it has a bias of $1$.

Returning to the sample average, suppose that the samples are drawn from any distribution (not necessarily Poison) which has an expected value (or mean) of $\mu$. Then

$$E[f(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)] = E\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right] = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i] = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \mu = \mu.$$

So in general, the sample average is an unbiased estimator of the expected value of the distribution from which the samples are drawn.