# Finding the condition on $k_1$ and $k_2$ of an unbiased estimator

Tags: statistics, estimation, maximum-likelihood

I'm taking a statistics course and am asked the following :

> Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent Poisson distributed values with
>   means $\theta$ and $2\theta$, respectively. Consider the combined estimator of $\theta$
>
> $$\hatθ = k_1 X + k_2 Y$$
>
> where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are arbitrary constants.
>
> (a) Find the condition on $k 1 $ and $k 2$ such that $\hatθ$ is an
>   unbiased estimator of $θ$.

How to approach answering this question ?

In order to find an unbiased estimator I need to discover the average of the distributed values of X and Y ?

From [how to compute unbiased estimator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418333/how-to-compute-unbiased-estimator/418358#418358) :

> A basic criteria for an estimator to be any good is that it is
>   *unbiased*, that is, that *on average* it gets the value of $\mu$ correct. Formally, an estimator $f$ is unbiased iff
>
> $$E[f(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)] =\mu.$$

If this were a simpler question such that  $\hatθ = k_1 XY$ then the condition on $k_1$ would be that $\theta\hat=E[f(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)] =\mu$ ?

But how to find the condition on $k_1$ and $k_2$ ?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate $E(\hat\theta)$ ? Equate the answer to $\theta$ and find the condition on $k_1,k_2$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom 'Do you know how to calculate (̂ ) ? ' - in this case no. what is the meaning of 'find the condition on k1, k2' ?

Comment: Then you need to check the properties of *expectation* from your notes/text. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Assuming $\hatθ = k_1 X + k_2 Y$

So in other words, your $\mu$ in the criterion is $\theta$ because it is the true value. You would require that the mean of the estimator is at the true value, namely
$$E(\hat{\theta}) = \theta$$
Hence replacing the estimator, we have
$$E( k_1 X + k_2 Y) = \theta$$
which by linearity gives
$$ k_1 E X + k_2 EY = \theta$$
But $EX = 
\theta$ and $EY = 2\theta$, so
$$ k_1\theta + 2k_2 \theta= \theta$$
means that our condition should be
$$k_1 + 2k_2 = 1$$

---

### Why do you say $\hat{\theta} = k_1 XY$ is easier ?

Assuming $\hat{\theta} = k_1 XY$, then $E\hat{\theta} = k_1 EXY = k_1 EX EY = 2k_1\theta^2$ which has to be equal to the true value $\theta$., so you'd require
$$k_1  = \frac{1}{\theta}$$which means that $k_1$ should depend on the true value !!!! So why estimate it :)